# input text box for url redirect with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an input type here which should redirect me to another page on the same site:
/Page1/Search!q= followed by the term(s) I've actually inserted in my input type box.
Any thoughts why the below code doesn't work?
On enter, nothing happens.
In Firefox I go to Tools > Web Developer > Debugger in order to set a breakpoint for debugging but in Debugger my Sources panel shows up empty. I was expecting to see my jquery function definitions there. Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input class="myClass" id="q" name="q" type="text" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.myClass').keypress(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
sp.myFunction($('.myClass').val());
return false;
}
return true;
});

myFunction: function (term) {
window.location.href = 'Page1/Search?q=' + term;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<input class="myClass" id="q" name="q" type="text" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.myClass').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        myFunction( $('.myClass').val() );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

myFunction = function (term) {
    window.location.href = 'Page1/Search?q=' + term;
}
</script>
```

You were missing jQuery library. `jquery-ui.js` is something else.
Secondly if you are viewing your files locally without any web server you need to add Protocol `http` or `https` in the `src` URL. The third mistake in your code was here `myFunction: function (term)` it should be `myFunction = function (term)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.myClass').keypress(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
   myFunction($('.myClass').val());
   return false;
}
return true;
});

myFunction = function (term) {
window.location.href = 'Page1/Search?q=' + term;
}
```